# Restrict access to server backend

Tags: android, ios, security, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm making a cross-platform application on Monodroid/MonoTouch, and my application should contact with server-side part to get data from it. Data is sensitive and is the base of application.

How would i defend it to restrict usage of server-side from other people/applications, assuming people can get correct request syntax or if i encode my query with secret key they can get that key by debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need **confidentiality** in your data transfers, e.g. using SSL/TLS, like HTTPS, but that alone won't be enough. By default it means that the client can ensure it trust the server, not that the server can trust the client (and that does not cover your *debugging* case).

So you'll need **authentication** as well. That's nearly identical to having a *secret* key except that it needs to be *user* (or the entity you trust) based, not *hard coded* into the application itself (that can't be trusted).

Having the users register and get passwords (or a user-token saved to the device storage) is one way to start this. It will protect your from *other people* using your data.

You can enhance this by creating some kind a user/device association so that a **user secret** can't be shared across several devices... that can limit the possibility of using an alternative (untrusted) application by the same (trusted) user, e.g. on a different device.

Comment: but people can register by the phone and then just replacing their environment variables to act like a phone..

Comment: You said *restrict usage of server-side from **other** people/applications* - emphasis on **other** people. If you don't trust your users then you enter the realm of DRM which IMHO simply does not work - you can make it hard but it's a matter of time before it fails. IOW you can't establish a trusted connection (for you data transfers) unless there's something you trust on both end (be it the hardware, the application or the users)

Comment: Other than what poupou mentioned, there is something you can consider: 1. you can generate UUID along with whatever you wanna generate to identify the app on a device and pass it over to server. For a web service based app, you can even pass them and their logins  as parameters for each web service call so you know exactly for each call where it come from. 2. On the server side, in the database, keep tracking logins and device UUIDs, keep them separated and flag them accordingly. You can add server side logic to monitor and do whatever you want from there.

Comment: @user1551009, yes they can trick your server but they don't have your app or server side code, it is not a url they can read from the browser. If you use HTTPS, it is safe from app to server in general. Of course you can argue that they have a chance to break the system, but no system is 100% safe. It depends how good they are and how much effort they put.

Comment: @RaymondWang yep, an UUID would be a way to create the **user/device association** I was talking about.

Comment: @poupou, yes I just wanna point it out, that's why I upvote your answer lol.

Comment: @poupou, there's still a problem of UUID, every time a user uninstall and re-install the app, the UUID will change. It is a shame that apple stop people from using UDID...

Comment: @RaymondWang agreed. The existing one had privacy issues but Apple could have provided an alternative. OpenUUID can help, see https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/